What language does GitHub copilot work with?
Currently I can only find this statement on GitHub copilot,

GitHub Copilot provides suggestions for numerous languages and a wide variety of frameworks, but works especially well for Python, JavaScript, TypeScript, Ruby, Go, C# and C++. GitHub Copilot can also assist in query generation for databases. The following samples are in JavaScript, but other languages will work similarly.

What languages and frameworks are included in _numerous languages and a wide variety of frameworks. My company uses Perl specifically.

The short answer is Yes!
Your question was one Google search-away and I found several articles and Reddit posts regarding the same. One of them goes like this:

I've used GitHub Copilot with Perl in a - well - minimal capacity over
the last two weeks, and I must say that I'm quite impressed. As long
as you know what you do, you can save a lot of time with its
auto-complete, which magically adapts to your current code and
environment.
Refactoring is also a lot easier/faster with it, and everyone knows
that encouraging refactoring - or code cleanup in general - is a good
time. :)

While Perl is not explicitly mentioned, GitHub Copilot's AI capabilities provide some assistance in Perl development, especially with common programming patterns and algorithms. However, the level of support may not be as comprehensive as for the languages listed explicitly.

The official supported list is buried under GitHub language support. There's a table listing supported languages of GitHub copilot. At the time of writing (Dec 2024), it supports: C, C++, C#, Go, Java, JavaScript, Kotlin, PHP, Python, Ruby, Rust, Scala, Swift, Typescript.
However, other languages may also work:

Most GitHub features work regardless of which languages your code is written in.

